# Can I create a foreign key constraint that also requires an arbitrary row on the parent table to be a certain value?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, data-modeling

As an example of this, let's say I have two simplistic tables and an ENUM:

```sql
CREATE TYPE role AS ENUM (
  'admin',
  'seller'
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  role role NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  seller_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id), -- Should only allow for 'role' of 'seller'
  cost currency NOT NULL
);
```

In order to create an order, there must be a corresponding user that was responsible for the sale. Only a user that has a `role` of `seller` should be able to create an order (e.g. a user with a `role` of `admin` should not be able to be a `seller`).

However, a user can have multiple roles. Currently there is no database-level check to ensure that `seller_id` can only refer to a `user` with a `role` of `seller`. Having checked the [contstraints documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html) I'm not completely sure this is possible without creating *another* table specifically for a seller (even though they function exactly the same otherwise).

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to solve these kind of problems would be to create a table `Seller` which only contains a `ID` column with a foreign key to `User.ID` therefore describing this user as a seller and when you require a `User` to be a selling user (e.g. the `seller_id` of an `Order`) you have a foreign key not to `User` but to `Seller` instead.